# Is there a function in typescript like __setattr__ in python?

Tags: typescript

When reading a project in Github, and trying to run it in the strict mode, I noticed that there is a error as follows.

```
class Calculator {
  public number1: string = '';
  public number2: string = '';

updateNumber(name: string, text: string) {
  if (this[name]) {
    this[name] += text;
  }
```

I am going to use

```
if (this.operator) {
  this.updateNumber('number2', text);
} else {
  this.updateNumber('number1', text);
}
```

to call the function. However the complier says

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Calculator'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Calculator'.
```

In python, I can use __setattr__ to achieve this. But what should I in typescript?

Comment: You could do something similar with a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Proxy) but it seems way easier to have two methods `updateNumber1` and `updateNumber2`.